# Show that contact manifolds are orientable, or why $\lambda\alpha\wedge(\lambda d\alpha+d\lambda\wedge\alpha)^n=\lambda^{n+1}\alpha\wedge(d\alpha)^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, orientation

While reading to Geige's An Introduction to Contact Topology, I got stuck after the following statement:

> Observe that $\alpha$ is a contact form precisely if $\alpha\wedge(d\alpha)^n$ is a volume form on $M$ (i.e. a nowhere vanishing top-dimensional differential form); in particular, $M$ needs to be orientable. The condition $\alpha\wedge(d\alpha)^n\not=0$ is independent of the specific choice of $\alpha$ and thus is indeed a property of $\xi=\ker\alpha$: any other 1–form defining the same hyperplane field must be of the form $\lambda\alpha$ for some smooth function $\lambda:M\rightarrow\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, and we have
> $$(\lambda\alpha)\wedge d((\lambda\alpha))^n=\lambda\alpha\wedge(\lambda d\alpha+d\lambda\wedge\alpha)^n=\lambda^{n+1}\alpha\wedge(d\alpha)^n\not=0\text{.}$$

For context, $\alpha$ is a 1-form that doesn't vanish at any point of $M$, where $M$ is a $(2n+1)$-differentiable manifold, and $(d\alpha)^n$ denotes the $n$-fold wedge product $d\alpha\wedge\dots\wedge d\alpha$.

I don't know how to prove the second equality, that is, why do we have that
$$\lambda\alpha\wedge(\lambda d\alpha+d\lambda\wedge\alpha)^n=\lambda^{n+1}\alpha\wedge(d\alpha)^n?$$
This would be trivial if we somehow had that $d\lambda\wedge\alpha=0$, which certainly doesn't have to be the case.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: A comment about your title -- it's not true in general that contact manifolds are orientable. It is true if the dimension of the manifold is $2n+1$ with $n$ odd, because then the sign of $\alpha\wedge (d\alpha)^n$ doesn't change when you replace $\alpha$ by $-\alpha$. But when $n$ is even, orientability of $M$ is equivalent to the existence of a global contact form, which might not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding $(\lambda d\alpha + d\lambda \wedge \alpha)^n$, you should get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n c_k\cdot (\lambda d\alpha)^{n-k} \wedge (d\lambda \wedge \alpha)^k
$$
where $c_k$ is a combinatorial constant.
Notice that $c_0=1$.
Now, any term with $k>0$ has some $\alpha$ term inside, and after a suitable permutation in the wedge products, one can write

$$
(\lambda d\alpha + d\lambda \wedge \alpha)^n = \lambda^ n (d\alpha)^n + \alpha \wedge \beta,
$$
for $\beta$ a $(2n-1)$-form.
Finally, $\alpha$ being a $1$-form, we have $\alpha\wedge \alpha = 0$, and therefore
$$
\lambda \alpha \wedge (d(\lambda \alpha))^n = \lambda^{n+1}\alpha \wedge (d\alpha)^n + \lambda \underbrace{\alpha \wedge \alpha}_{=0} \wedge \beta = \lambda^{n+1} \alpha\wedge (d\alpha)^n.
$$